# Can't assign Char variable from DataReader object (ADO.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I have created a Data Access method which uses ADO.Net but I'm having difficulty assigning one of my values. My reader has 3 objects, 2 strings and 1 char. The problem is when I try and assign the char to my char variable, cobType, in the code below.

```
using (IDataReader reader = ExecuteReader(cmd, transaction, false))
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                productType = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Product_Type"));
                cobType = reader.GetChar(reader.GetOrdinal("COB_Type"));
                payNonparProviders = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Pay_Nonpar_Providers"));
                return;
            }
        }
```

When I try using the above I get a runtime error:

```
"Specified method is not supported."
```

The GetChar method is suggested by intellisense but it seems not to work. I also tried using the GetString method instead but I can't cast the result into the char variable.

Comment: What type `IDataReaer` has? Is it `SqlDataReader`? Some custom reader?

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/494756/system-sqlclient-sqldatareader-does-not-support-system-data-idatarecord-getchar-int-i

Comment: It's a DbDataReader from the DbCommand class in System.Data.Common

Comment: Are you working with an Sql Server database? @SergeyBerezovskiy asked you about SqlDataReader because there is no implementation of GetChar in Sql Server Sql.Data.Client namespace. See the REMARKS here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getchar.aspx

Comment: I was able to use the solution in your other link, i.e. use GetString and index into the result so as to assign it to my char variable, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `GetChar` is not supported.  Instead I'm using `GetString(ordinal).ToCharArray()[0]`;